# firebase firestore import timestamp date

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I use a firebase import-export node scrip to seed some json data to firebase. I need to run a javascript date function inside the JSON file to get the date saved as firebase timestamp format.

```js
"updated": {
   "uid": "lVwMNLdzijfLz5XphJjPna8lBFN2",
   "createdAt": new Date("December 10, 2018")
 },
```

Since new Date is not a valid json format, my node script returns an error. If i save the value as a date string, it save it as a string in firebase which is NOT what i want. Any help?

Comment: "a firebase import-export node scrip[t]" Given that it's the script that handles the JSON and calls Firestore, what does it do? It will need to parse whatever you put into the JSON, and translate that to `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

Comment: Timestamp type fields don't have a raw JSON format that you can use for general import or export.  Your code will need to do something to construct a new Timestamp or Date object that the Cloud Firestore can understand.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Not necessarily a server timestamp, if we know the date.

Comment: Same problem though: since there is no JSON date type, you will have to include some marker in your JSON, parse that in your code, and then inject the correct value. If you're having problems in the code implementing this flow, share the [minimal code that reproduces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you guys. I contacted the owner of the package and got it resolved with the updated version of the package. cheers!